# Link for Android SDK plugins for Eclipse not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, installation

Brand new to Java and Android.  I have the Android SDK downloaded as well as Java and Eclipse.  I am watching the following YouTube video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TBNEOelTeM on "How to Install Android SDK".

The video is a bit older and the url that the presenter is stating to use for repository when installing available software on Eclipse is:  `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse`  However, this seems to be an older link.  What is the new link for the repository?

The following screenshot will help you visualize where I am stuck at:

[image]

I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is actual explanation of installing the ADT plugin http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

URL is correct,maybe you haven't internet connection

Comment: Internet connection is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're brand new to Android then you should really use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from the beginning. It's currently the official IDE for Android development.

Comment: Thanks.  Basically I was thrown on a project to build a prototype within 2 weeks.  Basically I just need to modify ODK Android code to customize map in ODK.  Can I still do this with Android Studio?  I was advised to do it this way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ODK so have no idea what problems you're facing. In general Android Studio should be able to do all of the stuff that Eclipse does, and vice versa - those are both IDEs valid for Android development.